# Closure - change for coins

Tags: javascript, closures

I want to understand Closure concept, so practicing  this exercise. However I am totally lost and confused. The task is to find  minimum of coins that  needs to be used to fulfil the total.As a result for £7.60  I would like to have an array 
res = [2, 2, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.1]

here is what I have so far:

```
function sortCoins (money, coins){
  res = [];

if(money % coins[0] !== 0){
  return  function(){
    do{
      money = money - coins[0];
      res.push(coins[0]);
    }
    while(coins[0]<= money);
    coins.shift();
  };
  // coins.shift();
} else {
  do{
      money = money - coins[0];
      res.push(coins[0]);
    }
    while(money !== 0 );
}

return res;


}

sortCoins (17, [5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1  ])();
```

I would really appreciate any help, explanation and suggestion what to read and practice to understand  Closure better. 
I saw the solutions for the similar Coins problem, but I do not want to just use it, I need to understand what I am doing wrong in my code.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working or should be improved, in your code?

Comment: @T30 Thank you for reply. Right now my res is undefined, I would like to get res = [5, 5, 5, 2], because it's  minimum of coins that needs to be used to fulfil 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return a function inside your `sortCoins`, which is kinda weird as you also return `res` inside your `sortCoins`.

Also, you have not defined a `res` variable, as you don't have added `var` before it, so is accessing a not defined global variable.

And the final one, as a tip, keep your indentation clean. You have a mess of spaces which makes the code blocks difficult to understand at first sight.

In short, the problems are the returns. Let me fix that:

## The function:

```
function sortCoins(money, coins){
    var res = [];
    // Use an index instead of modifying the array. Keep the parameters immutable when possible.
    var current = 0;
    do {
        money = money - coins[current];
        res.push(coins[current]);
        while (money < coins[current]) {
            current++;
        }
    } while(money > 0);
    return res;
}

// console.log it, to see in the F12 console tab
console.log(sortCoins(17, [5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1]));
```

## Closuring it:

We are going to create a set of coins, like this:

```
function sortCoins(coins) {
    // Notice that this function returns another function
    return function(money) {
        var res = [];
        // Use an index instead of modifying the array. Keep the parameters immutable when possible.
        var current = 0;
        do {
            money = money - coins[current];
            res.push(coins[current]);
            while (money < coins[current]) {
                current++;
            }
        } while(money > 0);
        return res;
    };
}

var myCoins = sortCoins([5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1]);
myCoins(17);

var myCoins_small = sortCoins([0.5, 0.25, 0.1]);
myCoins_small(17);

myCoins(12);
myCoins_small(12);
```

Take a look at the contents of the `sortCoins` function. With the correct indentation is easy to see that it returns a function. Not looking at the contents of the returned function you can see that is the only return it has:

```
function sortCoins(coins) {
    // Notice that this function returns another function
    return function(money) {
        [...]
    };
}
```

So, if you call `sortCoins([5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1])` it will return a function where the `coins` argument is set to `[5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1]`.

```
var myCoins = sortCoins([5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1]);
```

Now you have a variable `myCoins`, which is a function, where its `coins` argument is set to `[5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1]`. In other words, is like having this piece of code:

```
var coins = [5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1];
function myCoins(money) {
    var res = [];
    // Use an index instead of modifying the array. Keep the parameters immutable when possible.
    var current = 0;
    do {
        money = money - coins[current];
        res.push(coins[current]);
        while (money < coins[current]) {
            current++;
        }
    } while(money > 0);
    return res;
};
```

What happens if you call `myCoins(17);` in that last piece of code? If you look closely, it accesses the `coins` variable, so if you change the `coins` variable to `[0.5, 0.25, 0.1]` you will receive a different output.

How do you change it? Going back to the first `sortCoins(coins)` function, is as easy as calling it with another `coins` attribute:

```
var myCoins_small = sortCoins([0.5, 0.25, 0.1]);
```

Now `myCoins_small` has the `coins` attribute set to another different array and returns another function. Now you have 2 functions, `myCoins` and `myCoins_small`, each one running inside its own context which have 2 different `coins` attributes set.

In short. Closures in JS are limited by functions. When you tell the code to do something with a variable, it will look inside the current context (which is the own function). If don't finds the variable, will go up one level (that is to say, will look on the parent function) and look there, and if don't finds it there, will go up another level, and so on until reaches the so called "global scope" (In other words, the main level where the first lines of code run).

Here you can see it easier:

```
var mainlevel = 0; // This variable is declared in the global scope, so exists in ALL the functions

function level1() {
    var level1variable = 1; // This variable is declared inside level1 function, so exists in ALL the level1 function and its descendants

    function level2() {
        var level2variable = 2; // This variable is declared inside level2 function, so exists in ALL the level2 function and its descendants

        // level2 has access to its own variables and the one in his parents
        console.log(level2variable, level1variable, mainlevel);
    }

    // If I say level1 to access level2variable, it will return error as cannot access it
    console.log(level2variable); 

    // But it can actually access his own variables and the parent ones
    console.log(level1variable, mainlevel); 
}
```

With this and knowing that JS keeps the context of the returned functions, you can do awesome things as [currying](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/) (which is the thing that we made with the first `sortCoins(coins)` function).

If you get a bit lost, note that

```
function pepe(arg) {
    return arg * 2;
}
```

is the same as

```
var pepe = function(arg) {
    return arg * 2;
};
```

Both can be called with `pepe(2)` returning the same output. They have minor differences but not going to enter into details to not mess your head more.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation and recommendations!! But i have noticed that if I check the code with sortCoins(11, [5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1])) the result will be wrong.  And also it's no longer closure, which is still good to practice but I ideally want to understand the concept of returning a function within the function...

Comment: @Polina Updated with a fix and a detailed answer

Comment: thank you so much this is just the best explanation!

Comment: @Polina Glad you liked it :-)